# Call menu function in another function

Tags: c

I'm trying to call menu function in the main function and let it prompt until the user decides to quit, but seems like it's not giving me response..
I'm new at this website coding, let me know if there's anything eg. post format I can improve!

clearkeyboard function:

```
void clearKeyboard(void)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

The function to call menu:

```
void ContactManagerSystem(void)
{
    int contactchoice;
    int done = 1;
    char yesno, c;
    do {
        clearKeyboard();
        contactchoice = menu();
        switch (contactchoice) {
        case 1:
            printf("<<< Feature 1 is unavailable >>>\n");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("<<< Feature 2 is unavailable >>>\n");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("<<< Feature 3 is unavailable >>>\n");
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("<<< Feature 4 is unavailable >>>\n");
            break;
        case 5:
            printf("<<< Feature 5 is unavailable >>>\n");
            break;
        case 6:
            printf("<<< Feature 6 is unavailable >>>\n");
            break;
        case 0:
            printf("Exit the program? (Y)es/(N)o: ");
            scanf("%c%c", &yesno, &c);
            if (yesno == 'Y' || yesno == 'y' && c == '\n') {
                done = 0;
                break;
            }
            else if (yesno == 'N' || yesno == 'n')
                break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    } while (done == 1);
}
```

Menu function:

```
int menu(void)
{
    int done = 1;
    int choice;
    char c;
    do {
        printf("Contact Management System\n");
        printf("-------------------------\n");
        printf("1. Display contacts\n");
        printf("2. Add a contact\n");
        printf("3. Update a contact\n");
        printf("4. Delete a contact\n");
        printf("5. Search contacts by cell phone number\n");
        printf("6. Sort contacts by cell phone numbe\n");
        printf("0. Exit\n\n");
        printf("Select an option:> ");
        int rtn = scanf("%d%c", &choice, &c);

        if (rtn == EOF || rtn == 0 || c != '\n')
            clearKeyboard();
        else if (choice >= 0 && choice <= 6 && c == '\n')
            done = 0;
        else {
            clearKeyboard();
            printf("*** OUT OF RANGE *** <Enter a number between 0 and 6>: ");
            scanf("%d", &choice);
        }
    } while (done == 1);

    return choice;
}
```

Attached image below is where goes wrong, the correct version should do case 1 instead of keep prompt menu again.

**Incorrect Part**

[image]

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You need to validate the **return** of `scanf("%d", &choice)`. You need to handle `EOF` and a return of `0`. You must receive a return of `1` before considering `choice` to hold a valid integer. You must flush any characters that remain in `stdin` after a return of `0`.

Comment: You return an int from your menu function, but the switch in `ContactManagerSystem` is looking for a char.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm not sure about the return part, but I added clearkeyboard function. Post edited.

Comment: @RetiredNinja The menu function prototype is set by our prof. Does that mean I should probably use anything else other than switch?

Comment: The key here is `int rtn = scanf("%d", &choice);` then test `if (rtn == EOF) { /* user canceled input */ }` then `if (rtn == 0) { /* matching failure - clear stdin */ }` finally `if (rtn == 1) { /* I have a good value in choice */ }` after which you should clear `stdin` to handle input like `"3 ants go marching on again..."`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you for that, I've edited the code, might not be exactly same as what you said, but I tried :(

Comment: Read [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) (e.g. of functions like [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)) of every standard function that you use. Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and improve your code to get no warnings. [use the debugger, e.g. `gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two problem in your code.

1. menu() function returns `int` and you are matching `int` with `char` in switch case `case '1':` it should be `case 1:`
2. replace below line

`scanf("%c%c", &yesno,&c);` with `scanf("%c%c", &c,&yesno);`

hope this help you.

Comment: There are no methods in **C**

Comment: which method you are talking?

Comment: This —>> “menu() method ..”. In **C**, menu is a Function.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I've edited my code. I'm using char yesno to determine if the user wants to end the program or not. And the first character to be scanned should be either 'y' or 'n'. May I ask why you wanted me to put it like that(scanf("%c%c", &c,&yesno);)?

Comment: yes i mean menu() function. will update the answer. thanks

Comment: @zxc20100123 if answer is correct mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues to be improved.

1) Since `menu()` returns integer, switch case should have integers not characters.

2)

```
    printf("Exit the program? (Y)es/(N)o: ");
    scanf("%c%c", &yesno, &c);
```

You do not use `c`;

`scanf(" %c", &yesno);` 
is enough.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void clearKeyboard(void)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}

void ContactManagerSystem(void)
{
    int contactchoice;
    int done = 1;
    char yesno, c;
    do {
        contactchoice = menu();
        switch (contactchoice) {
        case 1:
            printf("<<< Feature 1 is unavailable >>>\n");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("<<< Feature 2 is unavailable >>>\n");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("<<< Feature 3 is unavailable >>>\n");
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("<<< Feature 4 is unavailable >>>\n");
            break;
        case 5:
            printf("<<< Feature 5 is unavailable >>>\n");
            break;
        case 6:
            printf("<<< Feature 6 is unavailable >>>\n");
        case 0:
            printf("Exit the program? (Y)es/(N)o: ");
            scanf(" %c", &yesno);
            if (yesno == 'Y' || yesno == 'y') {
                done = 0;
                break;
            }
            else if (yesno == 'N' || yesno == 'n')
                break;          
        default:
            break;
        }

    } while (done == 1);
}



int menu(void)
{
    int done = 1;
    int choice;
    do {
        printf("Contact Management System\n");
        printf("-------------------------\n");
        printf("1. Display contacts\n");
        printf("2. Add a contact\n");
        printf("3. Update a contact\n");
        printf("4. Delete a contact\n");
        printf("5. Search contacts by cell phone number\n");
        printf("6. Sort contacts by cell phone numbe\n");
        printf("0. Exit\n\n");
        printf("Select an option:> ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        if (choice >= 0 && choice <= 6)
            done = 0;
        else {
            clearKeyboard();
            printf("*** OUT OF RANGE *** <Enter a number between 0 and 6>: ");
            scanf("%d", &choice);
        }
    } while (done == 1);

    return choice;
}

int main(void)
{
    ContactManagerSystem();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Contact Management System                                                                                                                   
-------------------------                                                                                                                   
1. Display contacts                                                                                                                         
2. Add a contact                                                                                                                            
3. Update a contact                                                                                                                         
4. Delete a contact                                                                                                                         
5. Search contacts by cell phone number                                                                                                     
6. Sort contacts by cell phone numbe                                                                                                        
0. Exit                                                                                                                                     

Select an option:> 1                                                                                                                        
<<< Feature 1 is unavailable >>>                                                                                                            
Contact Management System                                                                                                                   
-------------------------                                                                                                                   
1. Display contacts                                                                                                                         
2. Add a contact                                                                                                                            
3. Update a contact                                                                                                                         
4. Delete a contact                                                                                                                         
5. Search contacts by cell phone number                                                                                                     
6. Sort contacts by cell phone numbe                                                                                                        
0. Exit                                                                                                                                     

Select an option:> 0                                                                                                                        
Exit the program? (Y)es/(N)o: Y
```

Comment: Thanks, I finally manage to make it work with you guys' help :D

Comment: @Great! I am glad that we helped. Please accept one of the answers.

Comment: You definitely help too, I gave it to Nidhi257 since (s)he answered first! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Just a few additional cleanups. You need to determine how to handle the user canceling input by generating a manual `EOF` with <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windoze). Since you are returning an `int` value, you can easily return `-1` for your `EOF` case.

Also, how many calls to `printf` do you need to make? One is enough, e.g.

```
int menu (void)
{
    int rtn, choice;    /* scanf return, menu choice */

    for (;;) {  /* loop until valid input or EOF displaying menu */
        printf ("\nContact Management System\n"
                "-------------------------\n"
                " 1. Display contacts\n"
                " 2. Add a contact\n"
                " 3. Update a contact\n"
                " 4. Delete a contact\n"
                " 5. Search contacts by cell phone number\n"
                " 6. Sort contacts by cell phone number\n"
                " 0. Exit\n\n"
                "Select an option:> ");

        rtn = scanf ("%d", &choice);    /* save scanf return */

        if (rtn == 1 && 0 <= choice && choice <= 6) /* good value, break */
            break;
        else if (rtn == EOF) {  /* user canceled input, return -1 */
            fprintf (stderr, "(user canceled input).\n");
            return -1;
        }
        empty_stdin();  /* empty_stdin for rtn = 0 case */
        fprintf (stderr, " error: invalid input.\n");
    }
    empty_stdin();  /* empty_stdin after good value */

    return choice;  /* return choice to user */
}
```

The C `switch` function provides *case-fallthrough* until a `break` statement is encountered. You can use this to your advantage in your CMS function until you fill all `case:` statements. You can continue to use fallthrough to handle the `0 - exit` and handle the `EOF` (user canceled input) return from `menu()`, e.g.

```
void cms (void)
{
    for (;;) {          /* loop continually calling menu */
        int choice = menu();
        char c;
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:     /* use case-fallthrough until setup */
            case 4:
            case 5:
            case 6:
                printf("<<< Feature %d is unavailable >>>\n", choice);
                break;
            case 0:
                printf ("exit program [y/n]: ");    /* confirm exit */
                if (scanf (" %c", &c) == EOF) {     /* handle EOF  */
                    fprintf (stderr, "(user canceled input).\n");
                    return;
                }
                empty_stdin();
                if (c == 'N' || c == 'n') {     /* handle no exit */
                    continue;
                    break;
                }
            case -1:        /* fallthrough yes exit or EOF in menu */
                return;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Putting it altogether, you can create a fairly robust little menu system, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void empty_stdin (void)
{
    for (int c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar()) {}
}

int menu (void)
{
    int rtn, choice;    /* scanf return, menu choice */

    for (;;) {  /* loop until valid input or EOF displaying menu */
        printf ("\nContact Management System\n"
                "-------------------------\n"
                " 1. Display contacts\n"
                " 2. Add a contact\n"
                " 3. Update a contact\n"
                " 4. Delete a contact\n"
                " 5. Search contacts by cell phone number\n"
                " 6. Sort contacts by cell phone number\n"
                " 0. Exit\n\n"
                "Select an option:> ");

        rtn = scanf ("%d", &choice);    /* save scanf return */

        if (rtn == 1 && 0 <= choice && choice <= 6) /* good value, break */
            break;
        else if (rtn == EOF) {  /* user canceled input, return -1 */
            fprintf (stderr, "(user canceled input).\n");
            return -1;
        }
        empty_stdin();  /* empty_stdin for rtn = 0 case */
        fprintf (stderr, " error: invalid input.\n");
    }
    empty_stdin();  /* empty_stdin after good value */

    return choice;  /* return choice to user */
}

void cms (void)
{
    for (;;) {          /* loop continually calling menu */
        int choice = menu();
        char c;
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:     /* use case-fallthrough until setup */
            case 4:
            case 5:
            case 6:
                printf("<<< Feature %d is unavailable >>>\n", choice);
                break;
            case 0:
                printf ("exit program [y/n]: ");    /* confirm exit */
                if (scanf (" %c", &c) == EOF) {     /* handle EOF  */
                    fprintf (stderr, "(user canceled input).\n");
                    return;
                }
                empty_stdin();
                if (c == 'N' || c == 'n') {     /* handle no exit */
                    continue;
                    break;
                }
            case -1:        /* fallthrough yes exit or EOF in menu */
                return;
                break;
        }
    }
}

int main (void) {

    cms();
    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Checking the cases where user cancels input either in `menu()` or at the `exit program [y/n]:` prompt by generating a manual `EOF` with <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windoze):

```
$ ./bin/scanf_menu_cms

Contact Management System
-------------------------
 1. Display contacts
 2. Add a contact
 3. Update a contact
 4. Delete a contact
 5. Search contacts by cell phone number
 6. Sort contacts by cell phone number
 0. Exit

Select an option:> (user canceled input).

$ ./bin/scanf_menu_cms

Contact Management System
-------------------------
 1. Display contacts
 2. Add a contact
 3. Update a contact
 4. Delete a contact
 5. Search contacts by cell phone number
 6. Sort contacts by cell phone number
 0. Exit

Select an option:> 0
exit program [y/n]: (user canceled input).
```

All good, now check a normal use case answering No to exit, then Yes:

```
$ ./bin/scanf_menu_cms

Contact Management System
-------------------------
 1. Display contacts
 2. Add a contact
 3. Update a contact
 4. Delete a contact
 5. Search contacts by cell phone number
 6. Sort contacts by cell phone number
 0. Exit

Select an option:> 4
<<< Feature 4 is unavailable >>>

Contact Management System
-------------------------
 1. Display contacts
 2. Add a contact
 3. Update a contact
 4. Delete a contact
 5. Search contacts by cell phone number
 6. Sort contacts by cell phone number
 0. Exit

Select an option:> 0
exit program [y/n]: n

Contact Management System
-------------------------
 1. Display contacts
 2. Add a contact
 3. Update a contact
 4. Delete a contact
 5. Search contacts by cell phone number
 6. Sort contacts by cell phone number
 0. Exit

Select an option:> 0
exit program [y/n]: y
```

Finally an invalid entry case:

```
$ ./bin/scanf_menu_cms

Contact Management System
-------------------------
 1. Display contacts
 2. Add a contact
 3. Update a contact
 4. Delete a contact
 5. Search contacts by cell phone number
 6. Sort contacts by cell phone number
 0. Exit

Select an option:> My dog has fleas!
 error: invalid input.

Contact Management System
-------------------------
 1. Display contacts
 2. Add a contact
 3. Update a contact
 4. Delete a contact
 5. Search contacts by cell phone number
 6. Sort contacts by cell phone number
 0. Exit

Select an option:> -1
 error: invalid input.

Contact Management System
-------------------------
 1. Display contacts
 2. Add a contact
 3. Update a contact
 4. Delete a contact
 5. Search contacts by cell phone number
 6. Sort contacts by cell phone number
 0. Exit

Select an option:> 7
 error: invalid input.

Contact Management System
-------------------------
 1. Display contacts
 2. Add a contact
 3. Update a contact
 4. Delete a contact
 5. Search contacts by cell phone number
 6. Sort contacts by cell phone number
 0. Exit

Select an option:> 4
<<< Feature 4 is unavailable >>>
```

While not an error, the standard coding style for C avoids the use of `camelCase` or `MixedCase` variable names in favor of all *lower-case* while reserving *upper-case* names for use with macros and constants. It is a matter of style -- so it is completely up to you, but failing to follow it can lead to the wrong first impression in some circles.

Comment: Wow nice one, this is bit over what I've learned. Thanks for your time and effort. am taking a look at it!

Comment: It does pretty must just what the others do, but it protects against the user canceling at each input and makes things more readable by simply using a single `printf` for the menu (C will put all sequential string literals together for you `"..." "..." "..."`) and by introducing you to the `case-fallthrough` which is part of the `switch` statement (It can allow you to tailor the `switch` as needed - or bite you if you forget to `break;`). Good luck with your coding `:)`