# Using fgets and strtol to get a single integer

Tags: c

I am learning C and I am trying to use **fgets()** and **strtol()** to accept user input and just take the first character. I am going to make a menu that will allow a user to select options 1-3 and 4 to exit. I want each option to only be selected if '1', '2', '3', or '4' are selected. I don't want 'asdfasdf' to work. I also don't want '11212' to select the first option since it starts with a 1. I created this code so far while I started testing and for some reason this loops over the question and supplies a 0 to the input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char a[2];
    long b;

    while(1) {
        printf("Enter a number: ");

        fgets(a, 2, stdin);

        b = strtol(a, NULL, 10);

        printf("b: %d\n", b);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

output

```
Enter a number: 3
b: 3
Enter a number: b: 0
Enter a number:
```

It should be:

```
Enter a number: 3
b: 3
Enter a number: 9
b: 9
```

Comment: You may want to visit [call menu from another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49397889/call-menu-function-in-another-function/49398972#49398972) for hints on implementing your menu.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have enough room for the `'\n'` to be read or else it will be left in the input buffer and the next iteration it will be read immediately and thus make `fgets()` return with an empty string and hence `strtol()` returns *0*.

Read [fgets()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3p.html)'s documentation, it reads until a `'\n'` or untill the buffer is full. So the first time, it stops because it has no more room to store characters, and then the second time it still has to read `'\n'` and it stops immediately.

A possible solution is to increase the buffer size, so that the `'\n'` is read and stored in it.

Another solution, is to read all remaining characters after `fgets()`.

The second solution could be cleanly implemented by reading one character at a time instead, since you are just interested in the first character you can discard anything else

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
    int chr;
    while (1) {
        // Read the next character in the input buffer
        chr = fgetc(stdin);
        // Check if the value is in range
        if ((chr >= '0') && (chr <= '9')) {
            int value;
            // Compute the corresponding integer
            value = chr - '0';
            fprintf(stdout, "value: %d\n", value);
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "unexpected character: %c\n", chr);
        }
        // Remove remaining characters from the
        // input buffer.
        while (((chr = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n') && (chr != EOF))
            ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you. I changed it from a 2 to a 3 and now it works. So it should be taking '3', '\n', '\0' now. But if char a[2]; only holds 2, how does this fit?

Comment: A string in C must always contain an ending `'\0'` (*nul-terminating character*), or it isn't a string, it's just an array of characters. All *line-oriented* input functions (such as `fgets`) will attempt to read-and-include the trailing `'\n'` in the buffer they fill (if there is room). If there is not room, any unread characters remain in the input buffer (e.g. `stdin`) just waiting to be read on your next attempt.

Comment: @bobdilly And... don't skimp on buffer size! `char a[512] = "";` or `1024` doesn't hurt (you have roughly a 4Megabyte stack to work with). I'd rather be `10,000` bytes too long that `1` byte too short. Be reasonable, but don't skimp. And always check whether the last character read by `fgets` was the `'\n'` or you know characters remain unread. E.g., `#include <string.h>` and test `if (a[strlen(a) - 1] != '\n') { /* line too long, handle error */ }`.