# Clang-Tidy: 'scanf' used to convert a string to an integer value, but function will not report conversion errors; consider using 'strtol' instead (C)

Tags: c

```c
int SchedulingMethodSubMenu(struct linkedList process[], int quantumTime, FILE *fp,FILE *fr,char *ovalue,char line[LINE_MAX])
{
    printf("1)Go Back to Home \n");
    printf("2)Exit \n");
    printf("Option >");

    int choice;
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    while (choice != 1 && choice != 2)
    {
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    }
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        system("clear");
        SchedulingMethodMenu(process, quantumTime, fp, fr, ovalue, line);
    } else if (choice == 2)
    {
        system("clear");
        exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hello, friends,

I get this error in my C project

> Clang-Tidy: 'scanf' used to convert a string to an integer value, but function will not report conversion errors; consider using 'strtol' instead (C++)

Can you help me if you didn't get the cause of the error?

Comment: [Sample `strtol()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63503107/2410359).  The best solution: drop `scanf()`   everywhere in code, use `fgets()` to read user input and then `strtol()` for this function.  I suspect that is too big a change for you though and the [real problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65576406/clang-tidy-scanf-used-to-convert-a-string-to-an-integer-value-but-function-w#comment115942644_65577066) you are having is not in this portion of code.

Comment: Did you read the documentation on `scanf()`? And did you think about the result, if the user enters something unexpected? The diagnosic message is clear on the topic: _[scanf()] will not report conversion errors_

Comment: You don't need `scanf` here, and even `fgets` is overkill.  Just use `getchar`.

Answer (score 4):

This is not an error message but as Warning from CLion, as suggested by @WilliamPursell use getchar instead.

```c
int SchedulingMethodSubMenu(struct linkedList process[], int quantumTime, FILE *fp,FILE *fr,char *ovalue,char line[LINE_MAX])
{
    printf("1)Go Back to Home \n");
    printf("2)Exit \n");
    printf("Option >");

    int choice;
    choice = getchar();
    while (choice != 1 && choice != 2)
    {
        choice = getchar();
    }
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        system("clear");
        SchedulingMethodMenu(process, quantumTime, fp, fr, ovalue, line);
    } else if (choice == 2)
    {
        system("clear");
        exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Other Stack Overflow questions

- [CLion recommends to use 'strtol' instead of 'scanf'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50795312/13903942)
- [What can I use for input conversion instead of scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537/what-can-i-use-for-input-conversion-instead-of-scanf)
- [Using fgets and strtol to get a single integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49460307/using-fgets-and-strtol-to-get-a-single-integer)

### Related

- [scanf in CLion](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009699699-scanf-in-CLion)

Comment: Shouldn't `1` be `'1'`? Also, perhaps a do....while loop?