# Can I use scanf multiple times and store the input in the same variable?

Tags: c, loops, input, char, scanf

I am doing an exercise in which my program needs to output 20 lines of a file and then wait for user input. If the input is the character `g`, the program should stop executing. Otherwise, it should print another two lines and ask for input again.

When I execute the program I am only asked for input once. That is, when I input a character other than `g`, the program keeps executing (as it should) but doesn't ask for input again, it just outputs the rest of the file.

I tried debugging it but I did not see where the error could be. I also tried getting input with `scanf()`, `fscanf()`, `getc()` and `getchar()` but the program's behavior doesn't change. What am I missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LINES 20
#define ESCAPE_CHAR 'g'    

    // Error checking, opening file, etc.
    // ...

    char c;
    int count = 0;

    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        // output
        putc(c, stdout);

        // increment count if character is linefeed
        if (c == '\n')
            ++count;

        // ask for character once 20 lines have been printed
        if (count == LINES)
        {
            count = 0;

            // exit loop if input is 'g'
            /* I also tried scanf(), fscanf() and getc() 
            here and the results were the same.         */
            if (getchar() == ESCAPE_CHAR)
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `getchar()` will read exactly one character. But if you type `x` and then press `<Enter>`, you've provided **two** characters: the `x` and the newline character. So your program needs to read all of the input characters up to and including the newline character.

Comment: But that doesn't explain why the program doesn't work with `scanf()`, for example.

Comment: My crystal ball is a little cloudy right now, but I guess that you forgot the space in the `scanf`.

Comment: It surely does. When you press `[Enter]` and generate `c\n' (where `'c'` is any character) -- what is waiting to be read the next time either `getc` or `scanf` (with `'%c'`) is called? (heaven forbid more than one character was typed) You can ignore leading whitespace by preceding your *conversion specifier* with a space, e.g. `" %c"`, but that doesn't cure the multi-char input issue.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin @user3386109 I did try with `scanf(" %c", &x)`, x being a `char` variable, and it worked. However, I'm having a lot of trouble understanding why. I'm still new in this, could you please explain?

Comment: The leading white space in the format string means "skip white space".  It skips over newlines and blanks and tabs.  Trailing white space is a disaster; it too skips over newlines and blanks and tabs, but it doesn't know to stop until you type something that isn't a newline, blank or tab.  So, the user has to be good at divining what the next input needs to be if you have trailing white space in the `scanf()` format string.

Comment: Well, it's actually pretty easy, but it requires you put your "accountant's" hat on to account for all characters that remain in the input buffer (`stdin`). You get pressing `[Enter]` generates a `'\n'` (which is considered *whitespace*). With `scanf`, a `space' in the *format string* consumes any number of whitespace characters (`space, tab, newline`) up to the next non-whitespace character. You can also remove multiple chars with `int c = getchar(); while (c =! '\n' && c != EOF) c = getchar();` Main reason `fgets` is recommended over `scanf`....

Comment: Doesn't a space in the format string expect that the value be preceded by a space? That's what I learned in my book in the I/O section. Or is that only for outputting and not for getting input?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin and how would I go about tackling the multi-char input issue? Storing input in an array and only evaluating the first element seems like an idea, but that's just using a bunch of memory...

Comment: The easiest way is define a function `void empty_stdin(void) { int c = getchar(); while (c != '\n' && c != EOF) c = getchar(); }` Then, after each input where at least one char remains in `stdin`, just call `empty_stdin();` We will discuss checking whether the user canceled input by generating a manual `EOF` by pressing `[ctrl+d]` or `[ctrl+z]` on windoze, later. You may want to review [Call menu from another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49397889/call-menu-function-in-another-function/49398972#49398972)

Comment: @AregSarvazyan "Doesn't a space in the format string expect that the value be preceded by a space?" --> No.  A space/white-space need not be present in the scanned input.

Comment: The return value from `getc` can be either a `char` value or EOF. To be able to distinguish them, `c` should be declared as `int`. This is probably not the cause of your problem, but there may be C implementations where `char` is unsigned, and then you will never leave the loop.