# How to stack the output for every loop in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I am trying to stack all the outputs together in this program only using basic loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main ()
{
    int n, i, age, hypo=0, mild=0, normal=0, mildhigh=0, modhigh=0, hyper=0, sp, dp ;
    printf("Number of patients = ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i=1; i<n+1; i++)
    {
        printf("What is the age? = \n");
        scanf("%d", &age);
        printf("Diastolic Pressure =\n");
        scanf("%d", &dp);
        printf("Systolic Pressure = \n");
        scanf("%d", &sp);
            if (dp>=35 && dp<=59 && sp>=50 && sp<=89)
            {
                    printf("\n                 Analysis  of Health Status                   \n");
                    printf("Age          DP in mmHg      SP in mmHg          Health Status   \n");
                    printf ("%d               %d            %d                 Hypotension\n", age, dp, sp);
                    hypo++;
            }
            else if (dp>=60 && dp<=69 && sp>=90 && sp<=99)
            {       
                    printf("\n                   Analysis  of Health Status                   \n"); 
                    printf("Age          DP in mmHg      SP in mmHg          Health Status   \n");
                    printf ("%d               %d            %d                 Mild Low\n", age, dp, sp);
                    mild++; 
            }
            else if (dp>=70 && dp<=84 && sp>=100 && sp<=129)
            {
                    printf("\n                   Analysis  of Health Status                   \n");
                    printf("Age          DP in mmHg      SP in mmHg          Health Status   \n");
                    printf ("%d               %d            %d                  Normal\n", age, dp, sp);
                    normal++;
            }

            else if (dp>=85 && dp<=89 && sp>=130 && sp<=139)
            {       
                    printf("\n                  Analysis  of Health Status                   \n");
                    printf("Age          DP in mmHg      SP in mmHg          Health Status   \n");
                    printf ("%d              %d              %d                 Stage 1\n", age, dp, sp);
                    mildhigh++; 
            }
            else if (dp>=90 && dp<=109 && sp>=140 && sp<=159)
            {       
                    printf("\n                   Analysis  of Health Status                   \n");
                    printf("Age          DP in mmHg      SP in mmHg          Health Status   \n");
                    printf ("%d               %d               %d               Stage 2\n", age, dp, sp);
                    modhigh++;
            }
            else if (dp>=110 && dp<=135 && sp>=160 && sp<=230)
            {       
                    printf("\n                   Analysis  of Health Status                   \n");
                    printf("Age          DP in mmHg      SP in mmHg          Health Status   \n");
                    printf ("%d              %d               %d               Stage 3\n", age, dp, sp);
                    hyper++;
            }
            else
            {       printf("Invalid input");
            }





            printf("\n      Summary of Health Status            \n");
            printf("Health Status                                      Number\n",mildhigh);
            printf("Hypotension                                           %d\n", hypo);
            printf("Mildlow                                               %d\n",mild);
            printf("Normal                                                %d\n",normal);
            printf("Mild High (Stage 1)                                   %d\n",mildhigh);
            printf("Moderately High BP (Stage 2)                          %d\n",modhigh);   
            printf("Hypertension/High BP (Stage 3)                        %d\n",hyper);

    }
}
```

Comment: So what are you asking? Please update your post with some more details about what you mean by stacking your output

Comment: please fix indentation. scanf and if-else should be at the same level

Comment: There is code duplication in the prints - this is error prone - consider adding a few static strings for mild/severe/stage3 etc

Comment: You [Only Need One `printf` for Multiple Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49398972/3422102) -- just an example of use. See `int menu (void)` function.

Comment: This is a huge program for a structural question. Perhaps reduce it to essence using one or two variables and re-ask. I suspect you want to use arrays to store values for each patient and write all the output with no intervening scanf. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you print the summary inside of the for loop. Move it to the other side of `}`

also the call to

```
    printf("Health Status                 Number\n",mildhigh);
```

don't take an extra argument as there is no `%d` in there.

As written in the comments, fix the indentation as it makes it easier for you to read the code, split all the print blocks to one set inside and one outside the for loop and use variables for the small thing that differ.

Answer (score 0):

The Summary of *Health Status* should be printed only 1 time at the end of the excecution. Therefore it should be only one time after the `for` loop finishes.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int n, i, age, hypo=0, mild=0, normal=0, mildhigh=0, modhigh=0, hyper=0, sp, dp ;
    printf("Number of patients = ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 1; i < n + 1; i++)
    {
        printf("What is the age? = \n");
        scanf("%d", &age);
        printf("Diastolic Pressure =\n");
        scanf("%d", &dp);
        printf("Systolic Pressure = \n");
        scanf("%d", &sp);

        if (dp>=35 && dp<=59 && sp>=50 && sp<=89)
        {
            printf("\n                 Analysis  of Health Status                   \n");
            printf("Age          DP in mmHg      SP in mmHg          Health Status   \n");
            printf ("%d               %d            %d                 Hypotension\n", age, dp, sp);
            hypo++;
        }
        else if (dp>=60 && dp<=69 && sp>=90 && sp<=99)
        {       
            printf("\n                   Analysis  of Health Status                   \n"); 
            printf("Age          DP in mmHg      SP in mmHg          Health Status   \n");
            printf ("%d               %d            %d                 Mild Low\n", age, dp, sp);
            mild++; 
        }
        else if (dp>=70 && dp<=84 && sp>=100 && sp<=129)
        {
            printf("\n                   Analysis  of Health Status                   \n");
            printf("Age          DP in mmHg      SP in mmHg          Health Status   \n");
            printf ("%d               %d            %d                  Normal\n", age, dp, sp);
            normal++;
        }

        else if (dp>=85 && dp<=89 && sp>=130 && sp<=139)
        {       
            printf("\n                  Analysis  of Health Status                   \n");
            printf("Age          DP in mmHg      SP in mmHg          Health Status   \n");
            printf ("%d              %d              %d                 Stage 1\n", age, dp, sp);
            mildhigh++; 
        }
        else if (dp>=90 && dp<=109 && sp>=140 && sp<=159)
        {       
            printf("\n                   Analysis  of Health Status                   \n");
            printf("Age          DP in mmHg      SP in mmHg          Health Status   \n");
            printf ("%d               %d               %d               Stage 2\n", age, dp, sp);
            modhigh++;
        }
        else if (dp>=110 && dp<=135 && sp>=160 && sp<=230)
        {       
            printf("\n                   Analysis  of Health Status                   \n");
            printf("Age          DP in mmHg      SP in mmHg          Health Status   \n");
            printf ("%d              %d               %d               Stage 3\n", age, dp, sp);
            hyper++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid input");
        }


    }

    printf("\n      Summary of Health Status            \n");
    printf("Health Status                                      Number\n",mildhigh);
    printf("Hypotension                                           %d\n", hypo);
    printf("Mildlow                                               %d\n",mild);
    printf("Normal                                                %d\n",normal);
    printf("Mild High (Stage 1)                                   %d\n",mildhigh);
    printf("Moderately High BP (Stage 2)                          %d\n",modhigh);   
    printf("Hypertension/High BP (Stage 3)                        %d\n",hyper);

    return 0;
}
```