# How can I link a data structure with another?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a shop system. I have a linked list and a stack. The linked list store the Person information (id and name) and the Stack store the Products (product).

I need to link both of them but I don't know how. I want to create some Person and the person will choose some products like:

Person1:

- Apple
- Orange

Person2:

- Strawberry
- Lemon

Every person will have their chosen products.

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define TAM 30

typedef int ID;
typedef char PRODUCT[TAM];

typedef struct stack{
    int nItems;
    int capacity;
    PRODUCT *product;
} Stack;

typedef struct person{
    Stack *stack;
    ID id;
    char name[TAM];
    struct person *next;
}Person;

typedef struct list{
    Person *head;  
    Person *end;
}List;

void createList(List *list){
    list->head = NULL;
    list->end = NULL;
}

void insert(List *list, Person person){

    Person *newPerson = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));
    Person *ant = NULL;
    Person *a = list->head;
    strcpy(newPerson->name, person.name); 
    newPerson->id = person.id;

    while(a != NULL && a->id < a->id){
        ant = a;
        a = a->next;
    }
    if (ant == NULL){
        newPerson->next = list->head;
        list->head = newPerson;
    }else{
        newPerson->next = ant->next;
        ant->next = newPerson;
    }
}

void printList(List *list){

    Person *a;
    a = list->head;

    while(a != NULL){ 
        printf("ID: %d | Name: %s\n", a->id, a->name);
        a = a->next;
    }
}

Stack *createStack(int capacity){

    Stack *stack = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    stack->product = malloc(sizeof(int) * capacity); 
    stack->capacity = capacity;

    return stack;
};

bool push(Stack *stack, PRODUCT product){
    if (stack->capacity == stack->nItems){
        return false;
    }

    strcpy(stack->product[stack->nItems], product);

    return true;
}

void printStack(Stack *stack){
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < stack->nItems; i++){
        printf("product: %s\n", stack->product[stack->nItems - i - 1]);
    }
}

int main(){

    int capacity = 10;
    Stack *stack = createStack(10);
    List list;

    Person p1 = {1, "James"};
    PRODUCT prod1 = {"Apple"};

    createList(&list);
    insert(&list, p1);

    push(stack, prod1);

    printList(&list);
    printStack(stack);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since `stack` isn't a linked list, you don't need a pointer to it. Just use `Stack stack;` in the `person` structure.

Comment: `while(a != NULL && a->id < a->id)` will never be true... Maybe you want to compare against the current `person` id??

Comment: @Fe2O3 you're right! Can you give me a suggestion?

Comment: Suggestion? Go back to basics and understand what it is you want. I'd suggest starting with a simple array of products. (Perhaps you can start with an array of structs that each initially only contain a product name, and can later be augmented with some other attributes like "quantity on hand" or something.) Then, form a second array of People structs (names only, to begin). When you've got these two arrays (and their helper routines like "print()"), the People struct can be augmented with an array of pointers (or indices) to elements of Products. Stick to simple data models. Draw it on paper.

Comment: On second thought... as suggested, load an array with your products (structs if you want), then load an array with people (again, structs with bits of info if you want.) Then create an array (or list or whatever) that _links_ one element of each of the two lists... Bob may have only a link to bananas, while Jane may have links to apples, oranges and pairs... The Product and People lists will be quite static, and you can play with the dynamic items that connect elements of one list to the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can do exactly what you are attempting to do, but you have missed the point of `Person` including `Stack *stack;` by creating a separate `Person` and `Stack` in `main()`. There is no relationship between the two if you create a separate `Person` and a separate `Stack`. Because `Person` includes a pointer to `stack`, you must create the stack when you `insert()` the person.

You are thinking along the correct lines in how you approach the list and stack, you are just struggling to get the pieces put together correctly and in the right order.

Let's start with your attempt in `main()` to create `p1` which you want to use as a temporary struct to insert. You declare and initialize `Person p1 = {1, "James"};`, but the first member in `Person` is `Stack *stack;`. So, of course, the compiler chokes when it sees `1` as the initializer for `Stack *stack;`. You can make your wanted initialization work by moving `Stack *stack;` to the 3<sup>rd</sup> member in the struct, e.g.

```c
typedef struct person {
    ID id;
    char name[TAM];
    Stack *stack;               /* move to 3rd member */
    struct person *next;
} Person;
```

When you allocate memory, you must validate **EVERY** allocation. If there are multiple allocations in any one function, if the 2<sup>nd</sup> (or later) allocation fails, you must clean up (`free()`) the prior allocations before returning an error condition. You can see that in `createStack()`, e.g.

```c
Stack *createStack (int capacity)
{
    Stack *stack = malloc (sizeof *stack);
    
    if (!stack) {   /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-stack");
        return NULL;
    }
    
    stack->product = malloc (capacity * sizeof *stack->product); 
    
    if (!stack->product) {  /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-stack->product");
        free (stack);       /* free stack memory on failure */
        return NULL;
    }
    
    stack->capacity = capacity;
    stack->nItems = 0;    /* don't forget to initialize nItems 0 */
    
    return stack;
}
```

As mentioned above, since the `Stack *stack;` is a member of `Person`, you must create the stack as part of creating the `Person`. (you can do it in separate functions if you like, but you create `Person->stack` NOT some separate unrelated `stack`). It is common to do it in the same function where you create your `Person`, e.g.

```c
Person *insert (List *list, const Person *person, int capacity)
{
    Person *newPerson = malloc (sizeof *newPerson);
    
    if (!newPerson) {   /* validate EVERY allocation */
      perror ("malloc-newPerson");
      return NULL;
    }
    
    *newPerson = *person;       /* assign automatic struct members */
    
    /* create / validate stack */
    newPerson->stack = createStack (capacity);
    if (!newPerson->stack) {
        free (newPerson);       /* free newPerson memory on failure */
        return NULL;
    }
    
    newPerson->next = NULL;     /* initialize pointers NULL */
    
    if (!list->head) {          /* good job on the end ptr, now use it */
        list->head = list->end = newPerson;
    }
    else {
        list->end->next = newPerson;
        list->end = newPerson;
    }
    
    return newPerson;
}
```

(**NOTE:** insert cannot be type `void`. You must return a type that indicates whether your allocation within the function succeeded or failed. Simply returning the pointer you create in the function (or `NULL` on failure) works fine.)

Your `push()` function should provide a meaningful error if the stack is full, e.g.

```c
bool push (Stack *stack, const PRODUCT product)
{
    if (stack->capacity == stack->nItems) {
        /* provide meaningful error messages */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: failed to add: %s (stack full)\n",
                 product);
        return false;
    }

    strcpy (stack->product[stack->nItems], product);
    stack->nItems++;    /* don't forget to increment nItems */

    return true;
}
```

(**note:** the addition of the increment of `stack->nItems`, without it you just keep overwriting the first product...)

Since your `stack` is part of `Person`, you need to `printStack()` as part of `printList()`, e.g.

```c
void printStack (Stack *stack)
{
    int i;
    
    if (!stack->nItems) {       /* don't forget to handle empty-stack */
        puts ("stack-empty");   /* or your printf() ivokes UB */
        return;
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < stack->nItems; i++) {
        printf ("  product: %s\n", stack->product[stack->nItems - i - 1]);
    }
}

void printList (List *list){

    Person *a = list->head;

    while (a != NULL) { 
        printf ("\nID: %d | Name: %s\n", a->id, a->name);
        
        printStack (a->stack);
        
        a = a->next;
    }
}
```

(**note:** the addition of the validation in `printStack()` to avoid *Undefined Behavior* by referencing a negative index if the stack is empty)

(**also note:** there is no reason to print the stack in reverse order -- unless you just want to. You are adding the product at `stack->nItems` each time so they will be in the order added)

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed. You do fine with (1), but completely fail doing (2).

Yes, since your list is created in `main()`, there is no technical memory-leak since the memory will be freed on program exit, but you will not always be creating lists in `main()`. In that case, if you fail to `free()` before leaving the function you created in -> memory-leak. Build good habits early, always track and free what you allocate. A simple routine to free your `stack` and `Person` nodes in your list could be:

```c
void del_stack (Stack *stack)
{
    free (stack->product);
    free (stack);
}

void del_list (List *list)
{
    Person *person = list->head;
    
    while (person) {
        Person *victim = person;
        del_stack (victim->stack);
        
        person = person->next;
        free (victim);
    }
}
```

Now you can simply call `del_list (&list);` to free all allocated memory.

Lastly, be very careful trying to be too creative with `typedef`. Never `typedef` pointers and make sure you understand a `typedef` of arrays. In your code you have:

```c
typedef char PRODUCT[TAM];
```

and then in `Stack` you have:

```c
    PRODUCT *product;
```

What is `product`? Is it a *pointer-to-array* or is it an *array-of-pointers*? (are you sure?) (hint: you have single-allocation, single-free, so it can only be one of the two)

Now in `main()`, it is fine to use a temporary pointer to `Person` to initialize and then insert in your list. But don't confuse the temporary `Person` with the node created in the `list`. Putting all the above together, and intentionally attempting to insert `12` products where only `10` will fit to exercise the checks in the code, you could do:

```c
int main() {

    int capacity = 10;
    List list;
    PRODUCT prod = "";
    
    createList (&list);
    
    Person tmp = { .id = 1, .name = "James"};
    
    /* must create stack with person */
    Person *p1 = insert (&list, &tmp, capacity);
    
    if (!p1) {      /* validate node & stack creation succeeds */
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < capacity + 2; i++) {
        sprintf (prod, "Product_%d", i + 1);
        if (!push (p1->stack, prod)) {
            break;
        }
    }

    printList (&list);
    del_list (&list);     /* don't forget to free what you allocate */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/llstack
error: failed to add: Product_11 (stack full)

ID: 1 | Name: James
  product: Product_10
  product: Product_9
  product: Product_8
  product: Product_7
  product: Product_6
  product: Product_5
  product: Product_4
  product: Product_3
  product: Product_2
  product: Product_1
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/llstack
==7287== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7287== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7287== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7287== Command: ./bin/llstack
==7287==
error: failed to add: Product_11 (stack full)

ID: 1 | Name: James
  product: Product_10
  product: Product_9
  product: Product_8
  product: Product_7
  product: Product_6
  product: Product_5
  product: Product_4
  product: Product_3
  product: Product_2
  product: Product_1
==7287==
==7287== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7287==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7287==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 1,396 bytes allocated
==7287==
==7287== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==7287==
==7287== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==7287== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

**Complete Example Code**

For easy reference, here are the complete modifications to your code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define TAM 30

typedef int ID;
typedef char PRODUCT[TAM];

typedef struct stack {
    int nItems;
    int capacity;
    PRODUCT *product;
} Stack;

typedef struct person {
    ID id;
    char name[TAM];
    Stack *stack;               /* move to 3rd member */
    struct person *next;
} Person;

typedef struct list {
    Person *head;  
    Person *end;
} List;

void createList (List *list) 
{
    list->head = NULL;
    list->end = NULL;
}

Stack *createStack (int capacity)
{
    Stack *stack = malloc (sizeof *stack);
    
    if (!stack) {   /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-stack");
        return NULL;
    }
    
    stack->product = malloc (capacity * sizeof *stack->product); 
    
    if (!stack->product) {  /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-stack->product");
        free (stack);       /* free stack memory on failure */
        return NULL;
    }
    
    stack->capacity = capacity;
    stack->nItems = 0;    /* don't forget to initialize nItems 0 */
    
    return stack;
}

Person *insert (List *list, const Person *person, int capacity)
{
    Person *newPerson = malloc (sizeof *newPerson);
    
    if (!newPerson) {   /* validate EVERY allocation */
      perror ("malloc-newPerson");
      return NULL;
    }
    
    *newPerson = *person;       /* assign automatic struct members */
    
    /* create / validate stack */
    newPerson->stack = createStack (capacity);
    if (!newPerson->stack) {
        free (newPerson);       /* free newPerson memory on failure */
        return NULL;
    }
    
    newPerson->next = NULL;     /* initialize pointers NULL */
    
    if (!list->head) {
        list->head = list->end = newPerson;
    }
    else {
        list->end->next = newPerson;
        list->end = newPerson;
    }
    
    return newPerson;
}

bool push (Stack *stack, const PRODUCT product)
{
    if (stack->capacity == stack->nItems) {
        /* provide meaningful error messages */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: failed to add: %s (stack full)\n",
                 product);
        return false;
    }

    strcpy (stack->product[stack->nItems], product);
    stack->nItems++;    /* don't forget to increment nItems */

    return true;
}

void printStack (Stack *stack)
{
    int i;
    
    if (!stack->nItems) {       /* don't forget to handle empty-stack */
        puts ("stack-empty");   /* or your printf() ivokes UB */
        return;
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < stack->nItems; i++) {
        printf ("  product: %s\n", stack->product[stack->nItems - i - 1]);
    }
}

void printList (List *list){

    Person *a = list->head;

    while (a != NULL) { 
        printf ("\nID: %d | Name: %s\n", a->id, a->name);
        
        printStack (a->stack);
        
        a = a->next;
    }
}

void del_stack (Stack *stack)
{
    free (stack->product);
    free (stack);
}

void del_list (List *list)
{
    Person *person = list->head;
    
    while (person) {
        Person *victim = person;
        del_stack (victim->stack);
        
        person = person->next;
        free (victim);
    }
}

int main() {

    int capacity = 10;
    List list;
    PRODUCT prod = "";
    
    createList (&list);
    
    Person tmp = { .id = 1, .name = "James"};
    
    /* must create stack with person */
    Person *p1 = insert (&list, &tmp, capacity);
    
    if (!p1) {      /* validate node & stack creation succeeds */
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < capacity + 2; i++) {
        sprintf (prod, "Product_%d", i + 1);
        if (!push (p1->stack, prod)) {
            break;
        }
    }

    printList (&list);
    del_list (&list);     /* don't forget to free what you allocate */
}
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you so much! I want to make an interactive menu, so the user can put all the information, how would it be? I want that the user create their "Person" (id and name) and after have a option to write all the products they want.

case 1:
        printf("Enter the ID: ");
        scanf("%d", &person.id);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter the name: ");
        fgets(person.name, TAM, stdin);
        insert();
        ...
        break;

        case 2:
        printf("Write the products: ");
        fgets();
        ...

Comment: @Leonhard - First ALWAYS keep your *Application* and *Interface* separate. Your *Application* is how you handle and process your data (the `List` and `Stack`, etc.). Your *Interface* is how you interact with the user. Don't mix the two. Write a function to display the menu and then use the return value in a `switch()` statement to call the function related to the menu item (e.g. `insert()`, `print()`, etc..). That way you can easily change a console app to a GUI app and you don't have to rewrite your *Application* functions.

Comment: Here is a question/answer that may help [Call menu function in another function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49398972/3422102)